# Retrieving the top 20% of a particular column in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I've created a database where workers have a charging rate and work a particular number of hours. From this I've done a select statement which simply displays some information about the worker, and then I've created a new column called `Earnings` which uses `rate_per_hour * task_hours` to give their total earnings.

My question is, is there a way to only display the top 20% highest earners based on the new `Earnings` column created in the select statement?

So far I have this:

```
SELECT worker.worker_id
    ,worker_first_name
    ,worker_surname
    ,worker_case_id
    ,task_hours
    ,rate.rate_id
    ,rate_per_hour
    ,task_hours * rate_per_hour AS Earnings
FROM worker
    ,note
    ,rate
WHERE worker.worker_id = note.worker_id
    AND rate.rate_id = note.rate_id;
```

I just need display the top 20% of earnings based on that new column I've made. Is this possible?

Thanks, apologies for my lack of experience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use explicit `join` syntax.  Second, you can do what you want using `percentile_cont()` or `percentile_disc()`.  However, I often do this using `row_number()` and `count()`:

```
SELECT wnr.*
FROM (SELECT w.worker_id, worker_first_name, worker_surname, worker_case_id,
             task_hours, r.rate_id, rate_per_hour,
             task_hours * rate_per_hour AS Earnings,
             row_number() over (order by task_hours * rate_per_hour desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) as cnt
      FROM worker w JOIN
           note n
           ON w.worker_id = n.worker_id JOIN
           rate r
           ON r.rate_id = n.rate_id
     ) wnr
WHERE seqnum <= cnt * 0.2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You also might use rank analytical function instead of row_number in case you want equal rank for equal earnings.

```
Select * from (
Select employee,earnings,rank() over (order by earnings desc )/count(*) over() As top from employees)
Where top<=0.2;
```